# Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey inside StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

thank you in advance for any support you can provide.

I am new to Flutter/Dart and I am developing an app which uses Firestore alongside Flutter. I have a collection of 'users' and also a collection of 'players' Each user can add players and they are added to the players collection however only they can see the players they have added. This all works fine so far. I have created a screen which lists all of the players using ListTile which also has a trailing icon which opens up a modal bottom sheet to allow the user to edit the player details.

I have connected all of this to Firestore using a QuerySnapshot and StreamBuilder and at the moment I am recieving the error that 'Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey'. I have tried to do some reading on this and looked at implementing lists fo global keys but also could not get that to work.Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
class _PlayerDetailsFormState extends State<PlayerDetailsForm> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _playerStream =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('players').snapshots();

  //form values
  late String _currentName;
  int _currentHandicap = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<MyUser?>(context);

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _playerStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        print(snapshot);
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }
        return new ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            return Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Update your player details',
                    style:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
                        labelText: 'Name', hintText: 'Enter your name'),
                    validator: (val) =>
                        val!.isEmpty ? 'Please enter a name' : null,
                    onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentName = val),
                    initialValue: document.get('name'),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 15.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Select your Handicap',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 40.0,
                  ),
                  SfSlider(
                    min: 0.0,
                    max: 40.0,
                    value: (_currentHandicap ?? document.get('handicap'))
                        .toDouble(),
                    interval: 5,
                    onChanged: (val) =>
                        setState(() => _currentHandicap = val.round()),
                    showTicks: true,
                    showLabels: true,
                    enableTooltip: true,
                    minorTicksPerInterval: 1,
                    activeColor: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 25.0,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        await DatabaseService(uid: user!.uid).updatePlayersData(
                            user.uid, _currentName, _currentHandicap);
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      }
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.green, fixedSize: Size(220.0, 32.0)),
                    child: Text(
                      'Save Changes',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 24.0,
                        letterSpacing: 2.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        await DatabaseService(uid: user!.uid)
                            .deletePlayersData();
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      }
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.red, fixedSize: Size(180.0, 28.0)),
                    child: Text(
                      'Delete Player',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that each player has a Form and all the forms share the same GlobalKey.

Comment: OK. How do I go about solving this? I have tried reading up on this issue but the solutions seem confusing to me. Do i need to assign a new key to each form?